# AWS Python SDK Boto3 EMR client.get_waiter("step_complete") Failing

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-emr

I have a python script that uses the AWS Python SDK, Boto3, to instantiate a new EMR cluster with a list of steps to complete and then uses the client.get_waiter("step_complete") function to wait for the steps to finish. This command works sporadically and every once in a while I get an exception saying the command has failed. It's strange to me that sometimes the code works and randomly it doesn't.

```
my_waiter = client.get_waiter("step_complete")
my_waiter .wait(
    ClusterId=jobFlowId,
    StepId=stepId,
    WaiterConfig={
        "Delay": 60,
        "MaxAttempts": 40
    }
)
```

Exception:

```
[2018-07-23 19:20:40,512] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:20:40,511] {connectionpool.py:203} INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 1.2.3.4
[2018-07-23 19:20:40,514] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:20:40,514] {connectionpool.py:203} INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): 1.2.3.4
[2018-07-23 19:20:40,551] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:20:40,550] {connectionpool.py:735} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): foobar-config.s3.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:20:40,733] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:20:40,733] {connectionpool.py:735} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:21:41,531] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:21:41,531] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:22:41,727] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:22:41,726] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:23:41,875] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:23:41,875] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:24:42,061] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:24:42,061] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:25:42,212] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:25:42,212] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:26:42,429] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:26:42,428] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:27:42,639] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:27:42,639] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:28:42,782] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:28:42,782] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:29:42,938] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:29:42,938] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:30:43,171] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:30:43,170] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:31:43,409] {base_task_runner.py:98} INFO - Subtask: [2018-07-23 19:31:43,408] {connectionpool.py:238} INFO - Resetting dropped connection: elasticmapreduce.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[2018-07-23 19:31:43,605] {models.py:1595} ERROR - Waiter StepComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1493, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 89, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 94, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/airflow/resources/emr-scripts/arl_emr_with_policyagent.py", line 366, in main
    "MaxAttempts": 40
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 53, in wait
    Waiter.wait(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/waiter.py", line 323, in wait
    last_response=response,
botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter StepComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state
[2018-07-23 19:31:43,606] {models.py:1624} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
[2018-07-23 19:31:43,636] {models.py:1644} ERROR - Waiter StepComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state
```

**Update:**

I forgot to mention that the steps are all passing on the EMR Cluster. I can see on the AWS Management Console that everything in the EMR succeed.There are no errors other than the waiter failing.

**Update 2:**

For people coming back to this I ended up just making my own waiter function

```
import logging
import boto3
import json
import sys
import time

def emrWaiter(cluster_id, step_id):

    # Range is number of minutes to wait
    rangeValue = 480
    for attempt in range(rangeValue):

        # Refresh the client
        client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1')

        step_status = client.describe_step(
            ClusterId=cluster_id,
            StepId=step_id
        )

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "COMPLETED":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step has finished")
            # Finished
            break

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "PENDING":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step is pending")
            # Sleep for one minute
            time.sleep(60)

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "RUNNING":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step is running")
            # Sleep for one minute
            time.sleep(60)

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "CANCEL_PENDING":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step Failed")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task failed with CANCEL_PENDING')

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "CANCELLED":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step Failed")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task failed with CANCELLED')

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "FAILED":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step Failed")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task failed with FAILED')

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "INTERRUPTED":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step Failed")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task failed with INTERRUPTED')

        if attempt == (rangeValue - 1):
            logging.info(step_id + " - Task timed out")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task timed out')
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @kyle,

Here is little modified version for brevity

```
    import logging
    import boto3
    import json
    import sys
    import time
    
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    def emrWaiter(cluster_id, step_id):

     # Range is number of minutes to wait
     rangeValue = 480
     for attempt in range(rangeValue):

        # Refresh the client
        client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1')

        step_status = client.describe_step(
            ClusterId=cluster_id,
            StepId=step_id
        )

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "COMPLETED":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step has finished")
            # Finished
            break

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "PENDING":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step is pending")
            # Sleep for one minute
            time.sleep(60)

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] == "RUNNING":
            logging.info(step_id + " - EMR step is running")
            # Sleep for one minute
            time.sleep(60)

        if step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"] in  ["CANCEL_PENDING","CANCELLED","FAILED","INTERRUPTED"]:
            logging.error(step_id + " EMR step in {} raising exception ".format(step_status["Step"]["Status"]["State"]))
            # Failed
            msg=step_status["Step"]["Status"]
            creation_time = msg['CreationDateTime'].strftime('')
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task failed with :{}'.format(step_status["Step"]["Status"]))

        if attempt == (rangeValue - 1):
            logging.info(step_id + " - Task timed out")
            # Failed
            raise Exception(step_id + ' - Task timed out')
```

Comment: Hey @Arden. The abbreviated code is nice, but it may be better to comment a link to the code instead of adding it as an answer. It is more of a clarification or addition to the question rather than a new answer. Thanks for contributing! Hope to see you more in the future.